# ng-disabled in angularjs is not working for me

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I'm trying to enable and disable the button using some condition

I am able to disable the button using `$scope.isDisabled = true;` , but can't enable the button

Here is my code

HTML file

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" ng-model="isDisabled" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
```

Controller JS file

```
$scope.isDisabled = true; // here the button disabled (for me)

if (count >= 3) {       // it's always true          
      $scope.isDisabled = false;   // try to enable the button here
}
```

Comment: Is that complete code? Just curious whats the use of `ng-model="isDisabled"` with `type="submit"`

Comment: i'm using set interval to change the button enable and disable, initially is in state disable using '$scope.isDisabled = true;' and i'm try to enable the button

Comment: Add `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.isDisabled = false; `

Comment: Show the complete code or prepare a working demo.

Comment: Sample fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/L4NQz/  can not reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not use $scope.apply. That is not what it is meant for.
2. The button does not need to be bound to a model, try removing the ng-model from the button.
3. Also, if it is an input type of "submit" and you are not inside an ng-form, that might
   cause a postback and you might lose your state.

Here is a plunk that shows it working - i made some assumptions to get the plunk going. added an extra button that triggered the count increments.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QGYMqGHCKUoDGaY9WYhj?p=preview